# regex - how to identify specific char ? java

Tags: javascript, regex

i have this java code :

```
cssBody = ".header-hp{" +
                "float: left;" +
            "width: 330px; "+
            "}"
    Matcher cssMatcher = Pattern.compile("[.](\\w+)\\s*[{]([^}]+)[}]").matcher(cssBody);
```

and i cant match it, i want my regex with can handle any char between the [.] and the \s*, how can i do it ?

Comment: Any character or any *sequence* of characters?

Comment: can u provide input output example please?

Comment: Like XML and HTML, CSS is too complex to match with a regular expression.  You would be wise to use (or write) a true CSS parser.  That said, you are trying to match a literal `.`, but your CSS rule does not contain any periods.

Comment: i want the matcher will work with any string between the . and the whitespace. as example : ".header", ".header-hp", ".headr~hp".

Comment: You don't have any dots in cssBody, so your regex doesn't match!

Comment: my mistake, it is with dots, i will update it

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want to match `{` or `}` in the CSS selector rules unless inside a quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

You have a dash `-` in the string but `\w` doesn't match it, add dash in the regex:

```
[.]([\\w-]+)\\s*[{]([^}]+)[}]
//    __^
```